# AWS Cognito - Enable SMS verification on pool already created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-cognito

I've created an user pool with only email verification. Now I want to enable SMS verification but it seems to not be possible since the pool was not created with this configuration. Does someone know if I can enable SMS verification on my current pool without creating a new user pool and migrating the users?